# Getting constraint violation exception on deleting parent although i used cascadeType.all

Tags: hibernate, cascading-deletes, hibernate-cascade, all-delete-orphan

As per my requirement I have two entities company and contact which are associated with @onetomany mapping and I want to delete the company and its related contacts with it.
I have used the Cascade.All but still I am getting the constraint violation exception whenever I try to delete a company.

Model :

```
company
-------
private List<Contact> contact;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY ,mappedBy="company",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)

public List<Contact> getContact() {
    return contact;
}

public void setContact(List<Contact> contact) {
    this.contact = contact;
}

contact
-------
private Company company;    
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
public Company getCompany() {
return company;
 }

public void setCompany(Company company) {
this.company = company;
```

I am getting the following exception :

> > ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:146 - ERROR: update or delete on table "company" violates foreign key constraint
> >     "fk_6jbjhtdw6ak2in3ln4tlxm0dm" on table "contact"   Detail: Key
> >     (id)=(71) is still referenced from table "contact".
> >     org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
> >     execute statement   at
> >     org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:129)

Comment: Your contact is only referenced in the company you're trying to delete ? Nowhere else ?

Comment: yes it is only referenced to company

Comment: Did you active the sql log to check if hibernate generated the child delete query before trying to delete the parent ?